# How do I call stored procedures using Entity Framework Core in a .NET Core 3.1 console application?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a C# .NET Core 3.1 console application. I need to query a SQL database via stored procedures for data retrieval.

I've been trying to use NuGet to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore packages into the projects.

I get errors saying that Entity Framework Core 5.0 is not compatible with .Net Core 3.1. I've tried earlier versions of Entity Framework Core, but I still get compatibility errors.

Should I be trying to use Entity Framework Core with .NET Core? Is there a way around these compatibility issues?

How do I call SQL stored procedures from EF Core?

Here are the errors I'm seeing when I try to add EntityFrameworkCore.SQL package to my solution via NuGet:

```
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Foo.WebAPI'.
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 does not support any target frameworks.
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 5.6.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 5.6.0 does not support any target frameworks.
Error   NU1202  Package System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0 supports:  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
```

Comment: There are no compatibility issues as EF Core 5 is a .NET Standard package so it runs on .NET Core 3.1 without problem. Calling and mapping stored procedures is well documented too. Post the actual error text and youra ctual code.

Comment: If you want to use stored procedures though, why use an ORM? Or vice versa, if you have an ORM, why do you want to use stored procedures? If you only want to map the results to objects you could use eg Dapper or another microORM

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you were able to get around the install issues you were having with .net core 3.1->5.0 upgrade. One approach there might be to just start over with a new .net core console app targeted to core 5.0 and move all your buisness logic, etc into the new console app. If you did get through the upgrade issues, here's an answer to your question above.

```
var user = "johndoe";
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

from Microsoft Docs "Raw Queries" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Personally I try to avoic using SP's in code first EF like the plauge, but there are rare occasions where LINQ and EF cant handle the job and you have to goto SP's.